# Assert that list contains a value in Scala using PlaySpec

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using `PlaySpec` to test some classes and I can't figure out how to test if a list contains an item.

I keep on seeing examples that say I should be able to do `records should contain ("string")` but I just get the message:

> Cannot resolved symbol should.

I need to use `PlaySpec` so please don't suggest I just change to one of the other specs.

Currently I'm just using `records.contains("string") mustBe true` but I'd really like to be able to get nice exception messages if it fails.

Comment: Missing an import?

Comment: Maybe missing `import org.scalatestplus.play._`?

Comment: I have that import, otherwise PlaySpec wouldn't resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlaySpec provides only verbs provided by `MustMatchers` trait, if you want to use `should` add `Matchers` trait to test class.